# Axios Error: Network error while using Axios get Method in react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, axios

I am using `Axios` as a network provider in `react native` and when I try to implement the api I got `network error` randomly in both iOS and Android, I am using the default inspector to debug the issue, I don't think any error in this, but I got the network error, anyone help me to overcome this issue.

`here is my code`

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { API_KEY, BASE_URL } from '../constants';

const fetchConfigAPI = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/config`, {
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'x-tutor-api-key': API_KEY,
            },
        });
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error fetching config API', error);
        throw error;
    }
};

export default fetchConfigAPI;
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const fetchConfigAPI = async () => {
try {
    const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/config`, {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'x-tutor-api-key': API_KEY,
        },
    })
    if (response.status === 200) {
        return response.data
    } else {
        throw new Error(`HTTP Error: ${response.status}`)
    }
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Error fetching config API:', error)
    throw error
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: @irfan I am using the local host for API response, I found the reason behind the  issue in iOS and solved this issue in iOS by adding the below code in info.Plist 
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
 <dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
 </dict>
But I didn't get any fix for Android to the Local host Api issue

Comment: Can you send local url please